# C# программ "Рассписание"

Tags: c#

Добрый день, хотел бы узнать какой нужно проект создать, для написания программы расписания, хочу написать программу которая позволит составлять расписание (пары, учителя, кабинеты, (что бы не было все вперемешку) и самое главное что есть часы например что бы можно было распределить пары так что бы вычитались все пары на протяжении всего учебного года), но не знаю как и с чего начать, посоветуйте с профессиональной точки зрения. Что нужно знать (база данных, какие то фреймворки). Благодарю.

Comment: закрывать этот вопрос, с моей точки зрения не стоит. За задачу "Расписание" берутся очень многие студенты (ну как бы естественная для них задача), поэтому предупреждение для них об этом болоте будет нелишним.

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала вам нужно знать, что задача "Расписание" является классическим примером трудноформализируемой задачи. Поэтому, если формализацию этой задачи (подготовку техусловий) вы не можете спихнуть на кого то другого (и соответственно ответственность), то нужно взять карандаш и ОЧЕНЬ четко прописать что именно вы собираетесь реализовывать, ПО САМОМУ МИНИМУМУ, а потом упираться рогом, но за этот минимум не выходить, иначе загребетесь. Задача угробила множество самоуверенных  студентов.

Comment: Это больше похоже на просьбу проработать вопрос, чем на ответ. У вас с недавних пор появилась возможность голосовать за закрытие вопросов, что имеет смысл рассмотреть, если на ваш взгляд хороший ответ на вопрос в текущем виде невозможен. Возможные причины для закрытия указаны в диалоговом окне за ссылкой "закрыть" под вопросом.

Comment: а ещё задача о расписании NP - полная насколько я помню.

Comment: @D-side, вот закрывать этот вопрос, с моей точки зрения не стоит. За задачу "Расписание" берутся очень многие студенты (ну как бы естественная для них задача), поэтому предупреждение для них об этом болоте будет нелишним.

Comment: Будьте добры, объясните в чем проблема данной задачи? На мой взгляд, проблема состоит в том, чтобы не было больших окон между парами для преподавателя / студентов. Все остальные проблемы больше логические - требуется ли компьютерный класс, разумно ли вообще в это время ставить этот предмет, и какие пары лучше склеивать ( 2 математики подряд, например ).

Comment: @Trymount, ну вот вам например еще одна проблемка - часть преподавателей работает по совместительству в других институтах, для ваших расчетов понадобится, де факто, учитывать расписание этих институтов. И еще проблема больничные. Я уже не говорю о вопросах о которых вам не скажут - например о "мертвых душах", блатных, и о том что раз Пересири Анадреич декан - то он не собирается выходить на работу раньше 11 (все это выплывет позже). Для конкретной кафедры все это можно ,в теории, учесть, но это связано с ограниченностью самой кафедры, какие либо изменения и ваша программа станет неадекватна.

Comment: @Mirdin преподаватели, работающие в других институтах, должны, наверное, заранее договориться о днях, в которые они работают в каком институте. Не будут же они туда-обратно ездить. То есть, на мой взгляд, добавить ограничение по дням и всё. А вот то, что декан к 8 утра в институт не поедет и он сам это расписание предоставит - это другой вопрос. Насколько я понял, не просят описать логику. Спрашивают как хранить данные и как их представлять.

Comment: @Trymount _Не будут же они туда-обратно ездить._ Почему? Понимаете в этой задаче плохо то что она сложно формализуются, по факту - каждому преподавателю и каждой группе - нужны будут свои правила. Тут есть один выход - "драконовская дисциплина" (подогнать учебный процесс под вашу программу), типа никаких совместителей, болезней и т.д. Какова вероятность этого? Но это уже зависит не от вашей программы, хотя виноваты все равно будете вы.

Comment: @Mirdin Живу на данный момент в Питере. Преподаватели даже между корпусов в течении дня не особо перемещаются) Ни разу не было замен в универе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44954/discussion-between-mirdin-and-trymount).

Answer (score -1):

Тип проекта зависит от конечного результата, который вы хотите получить.

1. Десктопное приложение
   1.1 Красивое представление приложения - WPF
   1.2 Быстрая, простая реализация внешнего вида - WinForms
2. Веб-приложение  Asp .Net MVC Application. Либо .Net Core, но с ним не сталкивался.